# Performant way of loading images in an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, real-time

I'm trying to display images at various refresh rates, and was wondering if there's a more performant way of doing so.

My current implementation works fine, except when I reach around 30+ fps in combination with heavier files (, which seems to incur significant slow-downs, causing old frames being displayed after newer ones, resulting in jarring pops & a stuttering-effect.

Right now, I receive raw image bytes from a Websocket, which I then use in the following way:

```js
cameraOutputSocket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
    document.getElementById("camera-preview").src = imageSrc;
});
```

Each individual frame is between 200kb and the objective is to reach 60 fps. I would assume the frame data would be available right when the socket handler is called (since I have access to `event.data`), but it seems like calling `URL.createObjectURL(event.data)` or `cameraPreview.src = imageSrc` re-downloads the image?

Is there a better/faster way to display image data in JS/HTML?

Comment: for 200kb per frame at 60 frames per second, you need at least 100mbit throughput between the server and the client - is that going to be an issue?

Comment: Instead of repeatetly querying the DOM, store the reference to the element with id `camera-preview` in a variable outside the event listener, most DOM operations are rather slow.

Comment: Your use case is exactly the reason why video codecs where created. I think you should try it in an canvas, the DOM is likely to slow to achieve your use case.

Comment: @JaromandaX My use case is limited to local networks, so bandwidth should in theory not be an issue (from iPhone to Desktop PC)

Comment: @Davi Yeah my example here was a bit truncated, but in actual code I keep a reference to the dom element and only query it once on page load

Comment: @Coli I've looked into using Canvas, but the way to load/paint image data still involves these `createURLObject` shenanigans? Or did I miss something 

Comment: @Skwiggs Okay after i reread your question I think I don't understand your question. How are you transmitting the pictures or are you only send an URL via websocket? I think a minimal working example of your question would help.

Comment: @Coli I send a Swift `Data` representation of a pixel buffer

Comment: @Skwiggs Then you should try [`createImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) I suppose.